# How to do I add strings to ClassificationDataSet?

Tags: python, pybrain

How do I build a dataset with strings in pybrain.datasets.addSample()? I'm getting an error which says "cannot convert string to float: gas".

Am I missing something, like an index value or a defined link between the input and target? I'm not sure how to read the documentation on this. Thanks for your help.

```
import pybrain
from pybrain.datasets import ClassificationDataSet

#set up input and target variables
ds = ClassificationDataSet(inp=2, target=1)

#add data to dataset
ds.addSample(('gas', 'blue'), ('car',))
ds.addSample(('desiel', 'brown'), ('truck',))

# error
ValueError: could not convert string to float: gas
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like pybrain only uses float types. Because of this, you might want to create a unique float value for each unique string variable. Maybe apply the ord() function to each character in the string, for each string in the tuple. Best practice is to use a list comprehension statement rather than map() and lambda functions.

```
>>> ord('a')
97
>>> ord('\u00c2')
192
```

or like

```
>>> [ord(c) for c in 'Hello World!']
[72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33]
```

so maybe like this:

```
>>>x = [('gas', 'blue'),]

>>>for var in x:
>>>    # for each letter of word
>>>    for c in var:
>>>        # list of ord() values for each letter of word
>>>        letter = [ord(i) for i in c]
>>>        # convert list to string
>>>        number = [str(i) for i in letter]
>>>        # join() to combine list into a single string
>>>        word = ''.join(number)
>>>        print c, word
gas 10397115
blue 98108117101
```

Representing strings as float type along with using Natural Language Tool Kit to represent occurrences of words might help in preparing your data for training a neural network model on.

[Python3 convert Unicode String to int representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625627/python3-convert-unicode-string-to-int-representation)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680250/pybrain-neural-network-nominal-string-inputs

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/869/neural-network-parse-string-data