# Generate an integer for encryption from a string and vice versa

Tags: python-3.x, rsa

I am trying to write an RSA code in python3. I need to turn user input strings (containing any characters, not only numbers) into integers to then encrypt them. What is the best way to turn a sting into an integer in Python 3.6 without 3-rd party modules?

Comment: `int('123')`? or what kind of strings do you mean?

Comment: Any string that a user inputs.

Comment: Have you tried looking into the `ord()` function which converts a character to its ascii value?

Comment: You turn the string into a sequence of bytes and then convert that into a big integer. Hopefully you're writing RSA for educational purposes rather than to use.

Comment: Could you provide your source code? Seems to me like an encryption question rather than string->int conversion.

Comment: Can you explain how can I turn the string into a sequence of bytes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

how to encode a string to an integer is far from unique... there are many ways! this is one of them:

```
strg = 'user input'
i = int.from_bytes(strg.encode('utf-8'), byteorder='big')
```

the conversion in the other direction then is:

```
s = int.to_bytes(i, length=len(strg), byteorder='big').decode('utf-8')
```

and yes, you need to know the length of the resulting string before converting back. if `length` is too large, the string will be padded with `chr(0)` from the left (with `byteorder='big'`); if `length` is too small, `int.to_bytes` will raise an `OverflowError: int too big to convert`.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I needed!

Comment: You should know the length of the plaintext to do the reverse operation?

Answer (score 2):

The @hiro protagonist's answer requires to know the length of the string. So I tried to find another solution and good answers here: [Python3 convert Unicode String to int representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625627/python3-convert-unicode-string-to-int-representation). I just summary here my favourite solutions:

```
def str2num(string):
   return int(binascii.hexlify(string.encode("utf-8")), 16)


def num2str(number):
    return binascii.unhexlify(format(number, "x").encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8")


def numfy(s, max_code=0x110000):
    # 0x110000 is max value of unicode character
    number = 0
    for e in [ord(c) for c in s]:
        number = (number * max_code) + e
    return number


def denumfy(number, max_code=0x110000):
    l = []
    while number != 0:
        l.append(chr(number % max_code))
        number = number // max_code
    return ''.join(reversed(l))
```

Intersting: testing some cases shows me that

str2num(s) = numfy(s, max_code=256) if ord(s[i]) < 128

and

str2num(s) = int.from_bytes(s.encode('utf-8'), byteorder='big') (@hiro protagonist's answer)