# python- reading certain number of bytes from a variable

Tags: python, cryptography

I'm trying to implement the AES algorithm, for which the message is to be divided into b-blocks each of 1byte(AES-128 would require 1 byte per state cell). So, if the message is: "This is saturday, and it is time to tell tale.", I'd have to read 1 byte out of this and store it in a state cell.

So, my first problem is, **Is it possible to read(or extract) a certain number of bytes from a variable?**

And the problem that follows immediately is, "**if it is possible to get a certain number of bytes from a variable, then, how do we obtain the bits in that byte?**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had to do that just recently. this is an option:

from itertools import islice

```
byteorder = 'big'
plain = b"This is saturday, and it is time to tell tale."

def chunked(iterable, n):
    it = iter(iterable)
    values = bytes(islice(it, n))
    while values:
        yield values
        values = bytes(islice(it, n))

for block_bytes in chunked(plain, n=8):
    block_int =  int.from_bytes(block_bytes, byteorder)
    print(block_bytes, bin(block_int))
```

which outputs

```
b'This is ' 0b101010001101000011010010111001100100000011010010111001100100000
b'saturday' 0b111001101100001011101000111010101110010011001000110000101111001
b', and it' 0b10110000100000011000010110111001100100001000000110100101110100
b' is time' 0b10000001101001011100110010000001110100011010010110110101100101
b' to tell' 0b10000001110100011011110010000001110100011001010110110001101100
b' tale.' 0b1000000111010001100001011011000110010100101110
```

note that the `byteorder` can be `'little'` as well.

from `block_int` it is easy to obtain the individual bits: e.g. the least-significant bit is `block_int & 1`; for bits in other positions you can shift: `(block_int >> 5) & 1` etc. or you get the desired byte from `block_bytes` (which is an array of `int`s) and select the bit you want; e.g. `(block_bytes[4] >> 7) & 1`.

maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44504397/generate-an-integer-for-encryption-from-a-sting-and-vice-versa/44504528#44504528) ia also helpful.

Comment: this is great thanks, although, turning a message into bits(like the way I have implemented here), is it good to implement AES like this?

Comment: most of the AES operations are byte-oriented... as i said: `block_bytes[3]` (e.g.) is a byte (represented as `int`). that should work nicely!