# Python: Reversibly encode alphanumeric string to integer

Tags: python, string, encoding, int

I want to convert a string (composed of alphanumeric characters) into an integer and then convert this integer back into a string:

`string --> int --> string`

In other words, I want to represent an alphanumeric string by an integer.

I found a working solution, which I included in the answer, but I do not think it is the best solution, and I am interested in other ideas/methods.

Please don't tag this as duplicate just because a lot of similar questions already exist, I specifically want an easy way of transforming a string into an integer and **vice versa**.

This should work for strings that contain alphanumeric characters, i.e. strings containing numbers and letters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's what I have so far:

#### First define an `string`

```
m = "test123"
```

#### `string` -> `bytes`

```
mBytes = m.encode("utf-8")
```

#### `bytes` -> `int`

```
mInt = int.from_bytes(mBytes, byteorder="big")
```

#### `int` -> `bytes`

```
mBytes = mInt.to_bytes(((mInt.bit_length() + 7) // 8), byteorder="big")
```

#### `bytes` -> `string`

```
m = mBytes.decode("utf-8")
```

#### All together

```
m = "test123"
mBytes = m.encode("utf-8")
mInt = int.from_bytes(mBytes, byteorder="big")
mBytes2 = mInt.to_bytes(((mInt.bit_length() + 7) // 8), byteorder="big")
m2 = mBytes2.decode("utf-8")
print(m == m2)
```

---

Here is an identical reusable version of the above:

```
class BytesIntEncoder:

    @staticmethod
    def encode(b: bytes) -> int:
        return int.from_bytes(b, byteorder='big')

    @staticmethod
    def decode(i: int) -> bytes:
        return i.to_bytes(((i.bit_length() + 7) // 8), byteorder='big')
```

If you're using Python <3.6, remove the optional type annotations.

Test:

```
>>> s = 'Test123'
>>> b = s.encode()
>>> b
b'Test123'

>>> BytesIntEncoder.encode(b)
23755444588720691
>>> BytesIntEncoder.decode(_)
b'Test123'
>>> _.decode()
'Test123'
```

Comment: This is clear &simple. And it's fast, because all the heavy arithmetic is performed by methods that run at C speed.

Comment: BTW, you can use negation to perform ceiling division. Eg, `-(-n // 8)`.

Comment: @A-B-B :) It's a nice benefit of Python's convention of handling signed operands of `//` & `%`. But it is a bit mysterious if you don't know what's going on, so I normally add a brief comment like `# Ceiling division` when I use it.

Comment: This was the most memory-efficient *and* the most straightforward solution. I rarely find a combination like that. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Recall that a string can be encoded to bytes, which can then be encoded to an integer. The encodings can then be reversed to get the bytes followed by the original string.

This encoder uses [`binascii`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html) to produce an **identical integer encoding** to the one in the answer by charel-f. I believe it to be identical because I extensively tested it.

Credit: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12627915/832230).

```
from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify

class BytesIntEncoder:

    @staticmethod
    def encode(b: bytes) -> int:
        return int(hexlify(b), 16) if b != b'' else 0

    @staticmethod
    def decode(i: int) -> int:
        return unhexlify('%x' % i) if i != 0 else b''
```

If you're using Python <3.6, remove the optional type annotations.

Quick test:

```
>>> s = 'Test123'
>>> b = s.encode()
>>> b
b'Test123'

>>> BytesIntEncoder.encode(b)
23755444588720691
>>> BytesIntEncoder.decode(_)
b'Test123'
>>> _.decode()
'Test123'
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the character set is merely alphanumeric, i.e. a-z A-Z 0-9, this requires 6 bits per character. As such, using an 8-bit byte-encoding is theoretically an inefficient use of memory.

This answer converts the input bytes into a sequence of 6-bit integers. It encodes these small integers into one large integer using bitwise operations. Whether this  actually translates into real-world storage efficiency is measured by [`sys.getsizeof`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof), and is more likely for larger strings.

This implementation customizes the encoding for the choice of character set. If for example you were working with just `string.ascii_lowercase` (5 bits) rather than `string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits` (6 bits), the encoding would be correspondingly efficient.

Unit tests are also included.

```
import string


class BytesIntEncoder:

    def __init__(self, chars: bytes = (string.ascii_letters + string.digits).encode()):
        num_chars = len(chars)
        translation = ''.join(chr(i) for i in range(1, num_chars + 1)).encode()
        self._translation_table = bytes.maketrans(chars, translation)
        self._reverse_translation_table = bytes.maketrans(translation, chars)
        self._num_bits_per_char = (num_chars + 1).bit_length()

    def encode(self, chars: bytes) -> int:
        num_bits_per_char = self._num_bits_per_char
        output, bit_idx = 0, 0
        for chr_idx in chars.translate(self._translation_table):
            output |= (chr_idx << bit_idx)
            bit_idx += num_bits_per_char
        return output

    def decode(self, i: int) -> bytes:
        maxint = (2 ** self._num_bits_per_char) - 1
        output = bytes(((i >> offset) & maxint) for offset in range(0, i.bit_length(), self._num_bits_per_char))
        return output.translate(self._reverse_translation_table)


# Test
import itertools
import random
import unittest


class TestBytesIntEncoder(unittest.TestCase):

    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    encoder = BytesIntEncoder(chars.encode())

    def _test_encoding(self, b_in: bytes):
        i = self.encoder.encode(b_in)
        self.assertIsInstance(i, int)
        b_out = self.encoder.decode(i)
        self.assertIsInstance(b_out, bytes)
        self.assertEqual(b_in, b_out)
        # print(b_in, i)

    def test_thoroughly_with_small_str(self):
        for s_len in range(4):
            for s in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(self.chars, s_len):
                s = ''.join(s)
                b_in = s.encode()
                self._test_encoding(b_in)

    def test_randomly_with_large_str(self):
        for s_len in range(256):
            num_samples = {s_len <= 16: 2 ** s_len,
                           16 < s_len <= 32: s_len ** 2,
                           s_len > 32: s_len * 2,
                           s_len > 64: s_len,
                           s_len > 128: 2}[True]
            # print(s_len, num_samples)
            for _ in range(num_samples):
                b_in = ''.join(random.choices(self.chars, k=s_len)).encode()
                self._test_encoding(b_in)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Usage example:

```
>>> encoder = BytesIntEncoder()
>>> s = 'Test123'
>>> b = s.encode()
>>> b
b'Test123'

>>> encoder.encode(b)
3908257788270
>>> encoder.decode(_)
b'Test123'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and for the time you put into this. Have a nice day, and I hope someone can benefit from one of your answers!

Answer (score 1):

so I needed transfer a dictionary in terms of numbers,
it may look kinda ugly but it's efficient in the way that every char (english letters) is exactly 2 numbers but it's capable of transfering any kind of unicode char

```
import json

myDict = {
    "le key": "le Valueue",
    2 : {
        "heya": 1234569,
        "3": 4
    },
    'Α α, Β β, Γ γ' : 'שלום'
}
def convertDictToNum(toBeConverted):
    return int(''.join([(lambda c: c if len(c) ==2 else '0'+c )(str(ord(c) - 26)) for c in str(json.dumps(toBeConverted))]))

def loadDictFromNum(toBeDecoded):
    toBeDecoded = str(toBeDecoded)
    return json.loads(''.join([chr(int(toBeDecoded[cut:cut + 2]) + 26) for cut in range(0, len(toBeDecoded), 2)]))

numbersDict = convertDictToNum(myDict)
print(numbersDict)
# 9708827506817595083206088....
recoveredDict = loadDictFromNum(numbersDict)
print(recoveredDict)
# {'le key': 'le Valueue', '2': {'heya': 1234569, '3': 4}, 'Α α, Β β, Γ γ': 'שלום'}
```