# How should I convert words that contain both letters and numbers into only numbers so that K-Neighbors classifier can train it to classify them?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nearest-neighbor

My training data contains of text like

```
EMI3776438, U9BA7E, 20FXU84P, 4506067765, N8UZ00351
```

I am using the K-Neighbors classifier algorithm.

Right now, the method I am using is to convert the alphabets to a number.

For example, `a`/`A` would map to `10`, `b`/`B` would map to `11`, `c`/`C` would map to `12`. After the conversion, I will send this data to the K-Neighbors classifier.

So, for example, `ABI37` becomes `1011I37`.

The problem with this method is that both `AA` and `1010` will map to `1010` and there is no way for the algorithm to differentiate them and classify properly.

Is there a good method to convert these to only numbers (since this algo only works on numbers) so that the real value and classification can be done correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53420705/python-reversibly-encode-alphanumeric-string-to-integer

Comment: Yes you can simply convert characters to int for example but this misses the key point that it does not necessarily give a meaningful measure of string-string 'distance' as needed fro k-nn to give something sensible.

Comment: It is common task in NLP, try using Word2Vec.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you first need to decide on a distance (or 'metric') for string comparison. Once you have a metric then applying k-nn to the data will be easy as k-nn just needs to be able to ask 'what is the distance between two data points?'. See [this Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric) article for ideas.

You can simply convert from characters to int as you suggest but this misses the key point that it does not necessarily give a meaningful measure of string-string 'distance' as needed fro k-nn to give something sensible. The choice of a best metric will depend on the particular problem details i.e. what your data actually represents!

[This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653157/a-better-similarity-ranking-algorithm-for-variable-length-strings) discusses a similar problem.